# Use eventClick in FullCalendar (in Shiny)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar in shiny that I would like to incorporate "eventClicks" into. Ideally, I would like for additional information to be shown in a pop up/hover over text box when clicking on one of the events within the calendar.

```
# CALENDAR
 LOL1 <- reactive({
 data1 <- calendar_subset()
 data1$CAL_DATE2 <- format(as.Date(data1$CAL_DATE2, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
 hope0 <- c(as.character(data1$Account_Num))
 hope1 <- c(as.character(data1$Billing_Num))
 hope2 <- c(data1$CAL_DATE2)
 hope3 <- c(as.character(data1$color))
 hope4 <- c(data1$Transaction_Amt2)
 fullcalendar(events = data.frame(
  title = c(hope0),
  start = c(hope2), 
  color = c(hope3),
  description = c(hope4)), 
options = list(header = list(left = "",center = "",right = "prev,next")),
callbacks = list(dayClick = DT::JS("function(event, jsEvent, view) {alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());}")))
}) 

output$test <- renderFullcalendar({LOL1()})
```

Ultimately, I would like to replace the "dayClick" in the code above with an "eventClick" or "eventrender".

Any ideas?

Browser console error:

```
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at Object.window.HTMLWidgets.evaluateStringMember (htmlwidgets.js:735)
at exports.OutputBinding.shinyBinding.renderValue (htmlwidgets.js:496)
at exports.OutputBinding.onValueChange (output_binding.js:16)
at exports.OutputBinding.delegator.<computed> [as onValueChange] (htmlwidgets.js:112)
at OutputBindingAdapter.onValueChange (output_binding_adapter.js:21)
at ShinyApp.receiveOutput (shinyapp.js:332)
at ShinyApp.<anonymous> (shinyapp.js:544)
at ShinyApp._sendMessagesToHandlers (shinyapp.js:529)
at ShinyApp.dispatchMessage (shinyapp.js:515)
at WebSocket.c.onmessage (shinyapp.js:112)
```

from the following code:

```
callbacks = list(eventClick = DT::JS("function(event, element, view) 
{alert('Billing Number: ' + event.billnum + '\\n'' + 'Amount: ' + 
event.amount);}")))
```

Comment: `callbacks = list(eventClick = DT::JS("function(event, element, view) {alert('Clicked on: ' + event.title);}")))` is probably a good start. It doesn't seem too tricky to just swap the callbacks over. Did you try anything? Are you stuck with anything else?

Comment: That worked! I was using "jsEvent" rather than "element" in the function!

Comment: Is there a way to combine more than one piece of information within the same alert? For example: the title and the description.

Comment: Yes, they're just strings, so you can concatenate them in the normal way. e.g. `alert('Clicked on: ' + event.title + " - " + event.description);`. This is basic JavaScript.

Comment: Ok. Did you check your browser's Console to see if there were any script errors? Or try to use the debugger? That might give you a clue as to the root cause of the issue. Perhaps there is a syntax error or something like that.

Comment: I believe the problem is when i try to add a newline instead of the two portions of the alert being side by side. Is there any particular reason why '\n' won't allow the calendar to show? When I don't use it, it works.

Comment: Can you show **exactly** what you wrote? And like I said, did it generate any errors in the browser Console?

Comment: I have added the browser console error and what I wrote to the question.

Comment: `'\\n''` - you have a stray extra quote mark which makes the string appear to be incomplete. And it should be `\n` - i.e. just one backslash. Otherwise you're double-escaping it, and it'll literally print the text `\n` in the alert, rather than actually creating a new line. So change it to `'\n'`. Demo, for comparison: https://jsfiddle.net/Lujfmver/ . N.B. I'd always recommend unit-testing your JavaScript code in a separate environment (such as JSFiddle for example) whenever you can (using dummy data, if necessary of course). Then you'll catch errors, especially syntax errors, much earlier.